# Program is going into infinite loop C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, file-handling

Below is the Program in which I have overloaded ">>" operator

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Student{
    public :
        string name;
        string entry_no;
};

class Science : public Student{
    public :
    float marks;
    void create_file();
    void highest();

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, Science& stud);
};

istream& operator >> ( istream& input, Science& stud){
    input >> stud.name;
    input >> stud.entry_no;
    input >> stud.marks;
    return input;
}
void Science::create_file(){
    ifstream file_read;

    file_read.open("student.txt");

    ofstream file_write;
    file_write.open("science.txt");
    string line;

    while(!file_read.eof()){
        getline(file_read,line,'\n');

        if(line.find("Science") != string::npos){
            file_write << line;
            file_write << '\n';
        }
    }
}

class Art : public Student{
    public :
    string marks;
    void create_file();
    void highest();
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, Art& stud);
};

istream& operator >> ( istream& input, Art& stud){
    input >> stud.name;
    input >> stud.entry_no;
    input >> stud.marks;
    return input;
}

void Art::create_file(){
    ifstream file_read;

    file_read.open("student.txt");

    ofstream file_write;
    file_write.open("art.txt");
    string line;

    while(!file_read.eof()){
        getline(file_read,line,'\n');

        if(line.find("Art") != string::npos){
            file_write << line;
            file_write << '\n';
        }
    }
    file_read.close();
    file_write.close();
}

void find_marks(){

    string entry_no;
    cout << "Enter entry_no of the student to find marks " << endl;
    cin >> entry_no;

    ifstream file_read;
    file_read.open("science.txt");
    string stud_entry;
    Science stud;
    bool found = false;
    if(file_read.is_open()){
        cout << (file_read >> stud) << endl;
    while( file_read >> stud ){
        cout << "hi";
        if(!entry_no.compare(stud.entry_no)){
            cout << stud.marks << endl;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    else
        cout << "error in openning"<< endl;

    if(!found)
        cout << "this student does not exist" << endl;
}

int main(){
    Science science_stud;
    Art art_stud;

    science_stud.create_file();
    art_stud.create_file();
    find_marks();   
    return 0;
}
```

Here while loop in function find_marks() goes into infinite loop if entry_no does not match. Can anyone explain why it is happening ?

Comment: Your while loop should be `while (file_read >> stud)`.

Comment: I suspect you are getting an error reading your file, but not eof.  Can you give a small example of a science.txt file where it fails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testing for `eof()` is only really useful to determine whether you want to print an error because the previous conversion failed or not. It is a really bad loop condition:

1. It isn't necessarily ever reached. For example, if the conversion fails at some point, the stream turns into fail-state where it refuses to extract further characters until the state is cleared.
2. The `std::ios_base::eofbit` flag isn't set when EOF is reached (at least, it isn't guaranteed to be set) but it is only guaranteed to be set once it was attempted to read past the end of the file. Thus, the last set of data tends to be processed twice.

The proper way is to just use the conversion to `bool` **after** the data was read:

```
while (file >> whatever) {
    ...
}
```

If your C++ tutorial advised you to use `eof()` you should probably burn it and advise others not to buy a copy (they would need to burn). If your teacher told you to use `eof()` - ... well, it is my understanding that burning people has fallen out of fashion. You should, at least, tell him that he is wrong.

Comment: I used above condition but in that case it never goes into the loop

Comment: @neel did you check if the file was opened successfully?

Comment: If I am using eof then it goes into the loop

Comment: @neel: This means that you don't provide a data set matching your attempted read! You didn't provide any indication on what types the members of your class are but I'd venture a guess that `name` is a `std::string` and `entry_no` is an integer. ... and, furthermore I would be prepared to bet that the input starts with something like this: "John Smith 17". In this case, note that reading the `name` just reads `"John"` and an attempt to read `"Smith"` as an integer which, clearly, fails. Of course, the failure to read even one input emphasizes that using `eof()` is the wrong thing...

Comment: I have converted name,entry_no and marks all into string but still not working

Comment: I had checked the output of file_read >> stud, it is returning 0.

Comment: @neel: Maybe you can share [the relevant part of] your code, the initial portion of your input, and make sure that the file is, indeed, successfully opened (`std::ifstream in("somefile"); if (!in) { std::cout << "failed to open `somefile`\n"; }`. Alternatively, test each individual part of your input (i.e., in your input operator) and display what it has read. After all, part of learning how to program is learning how to locate problems...

Comment: @neel: Yes, if `std::ios_base::failbit` is set (because the stream failed to read decode input or because it failed to be opened), the stream converts to `false` (or, `0` if you haven't set up binary formatting to use strings using, e.g., `std::cout << std::boolalpha;`). You'll need to find what causes the stream to get into fail state.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19049/discussion-between-neel-and-dietmar-kuhl)